# Maintain/keep all the PointCloud2 in Rviz

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am publishing PointCloud2 in Rviz, but when I publish the current PointCloud2 msg from the topic, the last msg will disappear, how can I maintain all the PointCloud2 in Rviz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308734/maintain/keep-all-the-pointcloud2-in-rviz/) by [zhonghao](https://answers.ros.org/users/38441/zhonghao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2018-11-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The PointCloud2 display has a "decay time" setting that defaults to 0 (i.e. only last cloud is shown). If you crank that up, all clouds that are not older than the number you select [in seconds] are shown in rviz. Depending on the type of data this might lead to very high CPU and memory consumption, so you'll have to try and see what works for you.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2018-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zhonghao](https://answers.ros.org/users/38441/zhonghao/) on 2018-11-16**:
hey Stefan, I just found the decay time as well. That's what exactly I need. Thanks a lot.